# Storing many objects using Java

Tags: java, dictionary, memory, collections

I'm reaching out to the community here to understand if there is a way to store many objects in a Java map structure (> 500K). I know at some point my application will exceed its memory footprint if I use the Java Collections API and I'm looking for other solutions (outside of distributed caching). My intention is to store something to the effect of Map<String, List<String>>.

Requirements:

- Structure will be immutable (one time load into the map). Only read access.
- Access to the map needs to be fairly quick but not looking for low latency retrievals, more concerned about storing and retaining these objects in memory.

Does anyone know of such a library I can utilize that can achieve this or has anyone ever come across a solution in which they were required to load many objects in memory in Java? I'd be very interested in hearing your feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: you said the structure will be immutable, but add "primarily read access."  what modification will be permitted?

Comment: sorry for the confusion...replace "Primarily" with "Only" ... no writes will be made after the objects are added to the map

Comment: 500k mappings from strings to lists of strings?  are there any common strings, i.e., among the values, or do keys also appear in values?

Comment: No common strings among the values...assume that it doesn't have to be a List<String> but rather List<?> ... and assume also that I'll need to store 500K+ unique keys.

Comment: depending on the type of your values, it may be suitable to keep them off-heap.  In-heap there would be a map from string to offset & length, which would point into a memory mapped ___Buffer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) would be perfect for this. At its most basic, it offers a key-value map, with optional overflow to disk, and optional persistence over JVM restarts. It will keep elements in memory that are most frequently used.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at EhCache barebone...I've used Terracotta before and I know internally it uses EhCache...I wanted to steer clear from distributed caches but looks like I can use EhCache standalone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with skaffman. In addition to the overflow to disk EhCache offers you to place the cache in-process but off-heap. If your cache is *really* big, this may have a very positive impact on performance since it reduces stress on the GC.

This specific feature however must be payed for, but otherwise EhCache is free.

Instead of EhCache, there are a couple of other caches in Java that offer similar or sometimes even more advanced options like [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan) or OsCache.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a read-only database, such as a java cdb: http://www.strangegizmo.com/products/sg-cdb/

Answer (score 0):

## *MVStore* feature of *H2 Database Engine*

While I have not tried it, the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) offers a specialized key-value store besides its relational database engine. This store is called [*MVStore*](http://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html). While used internally by H2, the documentations suggest you may use it directly for key-value storage.

MVStore lets you interact through the [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) interface, without using JDBC or SQL.

Example usage, taken from the doc:

```
import org.h2.mvstore.*;

// open the store (in-memory if fileName is null)
MVStore s = MVStore.open(fileName);

// create/get the map named "data"
MVMap<Integer, String> map = s.openMap("data");

// add and read some data
map.put(1, "Hello World");
System.out.println(map.get(1));

// close the store (this will persist changes)
s.close();
```

Read [the thorough documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html) to learn about its performance profile, concurrency, and ability to cache in-memory while also persisting to storage.